# imgix.com downloads images instead of browsing to them

Tags: cdn, imgix-js

I am using the imgix.com CDN for a test project and for some reason it keeps downloading the images instead of browsing and applying the rules to to them.

So if I type in `myprefix.imgix.net/myimage.png` it simply downloads it and if I type `https://myprefix.imgix.net/myimage.png~text?txtsize=44&txt=470%C3%97480&w=450&h=480` nothing happens.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate issues:

1) If you request an imgix URL without adding any query parameters, imgix will just act as a passthrough to your source. If your images are being treated as a download by the browser rather than as images to display, there must be something mis-configured at the source level. Not knowing anything about your source, I really can't offer any better advice here.

2) The `myimage.png~text` URL isn't working because you shouldn't be using `~text` at all here. Take those five characters out of your URL and it should work as you expect.

Imgix's `~text` endpoint is a way to request an image where the "base image" is text rather than a real image. In trying to combine a real base image (`myimage.png`, in your URL above) with this text-only endpoint (`~text`), you're making a request that imgix doesn't know how to handle.

---

If you've got further questions about your imgix integration, especially if they're configuration questions that involve your specific account and settings, I'd encourage you to send your questions to support@imgix.com instead of StackOverflow. While SO is a great place to answer one-off questions, writing into our support-ticket system will allow us to answer account-specific questions a lot easier.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. Will email you may account details to support. It is basically a dropbox image source folder, so I take it that you have to link to the source directly as opposed to its parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Once your Source has been configured and deployed, you can begin making image requests to imgix. These requests differ slightly for each imgix Source type, but they all have the same basic structure:
https:// example.imgix.net imgix domain  / products/desk.jpg path  ? w=600&exp=1 query string
The hostname, or domain, of the imgix URL will have the form YOUR_SOURCE_NAME.imgix.net. In the above URL, the name of the Source is example, so the hostname takes the form of example.imgix.net. Different hostnames can be set in your Source by clicking Manage under the Domains header.
The path consists of any additional directory information required to locate your image within your image storage (e.g. if you have different subfolders for your images). In this example, /products/desk.jpg completes the full path to the image.
imgix’s parameters are added to the query string of the URL. In the above example, the query string begins with ?w=600 and the additional parameters are linked with ampersands. These parameters dictate how images are processed. In the above URL, w=600 specifies the width of the image and exp=1 adjusts the exposure setting.